# How to find index of ArrayList item in String Array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to find `ArrayList<String>` item's index in String Array but every time `indexOf()` give -1 index .

I cant understand where is wrong? Please check my code and guide me.

```
public static void arrangeUiComponent() {

    ArrayList<String> packageName = new ArrayList<String>();
    packageName.add("com.example.dummy");
    packageName.add("edu.app.reading");
    ArrayList<Integer> index = getIndex(packageName);

}
```

// searching method

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> getIndex(ArrayList<String> searchName) {

    ArrayList<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] collectionData = new String[] { "com.example.app",
            "com.example.appdemo", "com.example.dummy", "edu.app.reading",
            "edu.app.knowledge" };

    /*
     * for iterating each and every item of list
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < searchName.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("MISSION", "value will be: " + searchName.get(i).toString());
        /*
         * for searching listItem in package name array
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < collectionData.length; j++) {
            indexList.add(collectionData.toString().indexOf(searchName.get(i).toString()));
            break;
        }
    }
    return indexList;
}
```

Comment: @jhamon i have already check it that fine....

Comment: Your collectionData is a String[] which does not have the nice pretty printing as collections. collectionData.toString() gives you something as [Ljava.lang.String;@58ceff1 which is not met by th search names. Use a collection for the collection data and the results will differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
    for (int j = 0; j < collectionData.length; j++) {
        indexList.add(collectionData.toString().indexOf(searchName.get(i).toString()));
        break;
    }
```

with

```
      indexList.add(Arrays.asList(collectionData).indexOf(searchName.get(i)));
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/BnYW6f) is the working demo of your code. `Arrays.asList` converts your `string array` to a `list`. Why don't you use a `list` instead of `string collectionData array`?

Comment: You shouldn't use asList inside the loop.
It will create a new LIst everytime, so will be slower when the packageName array becomes large.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I understand which is why I asked OP why not use a `list` instead of an `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a debugger and look the value of `collectionData.toString()`.
It returns something that is not your list of strings. That the object representation.
Quote from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object.

**EDIT:**
whoops, `collectionData`is an array, not a List, you should use

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(collectionData).indexOf(searchName.get(i))
```

It will search for the `searchName.get(i)`string inside the `collectionData`List and not inside the `collectionData` representation which is a String (that's why indexOf is valid).

As `searchName` is a list of String, you don't need to add the `toString()` on `searchName.get(i)`

Comment: i try collectionData.indexOf(searchName.get(i)) this but it show error :Cannot invoke indexOf(String) on the array type String[]

Comment: Shooting too fast heh =)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that in the `indexLIst` you want corresponding `packageName's` index values.


I don't think this will work in the way you want it.
The `indexList` being an `Arraylist`(data is not stored in the input order) might not have corresponding index values.

**Ex:**

packageName list:
"com.example.dummy", "edu.app.reading" 

so the `indexList` should have values:
2 , 3

but it might contain:
3, 2 as well because data is not stored in the order in which it is entered.

You should probably use a `linkedList` if you want to preserve the order.
 use a `Hashmap<String, integer>`.

You can do something like this using a hashmap:

```
public static void arrangeUiComponent() {

        ArrayList<String> packageName = new ArrayList<String>();
        packageName.add("com.example.dummy");
        packageName.add("edu.app.reading");
        HashMap<String, Integer> indexMap = getIndex(packageName);
        for (String s : packageName) {
            int index = indexMap.get(s);
        }

    }

    private static HashMap<String, Integer> getIndex(ArrayList<String> searchName) {

        HashMap<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] collectionData = new String[] { "com.example.app", "com.example.appdemo", "com.example.dummy",
                "edu.app.reading", "edu.app.knowledge" };

        for (String search : searchName) {
            for (int i = 0; i < collectionData.length; i++) {
                if (search.equals(collectionData[i])) {
                    indexMap.put(search, i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return indexMap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `collectionData.toString()` which return `[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742`. So `collectionData.toString().indexof()` always find nothing and return `-1`

**To solve this you can use:**

Declare arraylist as

```
ArrayList<String>cd = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(collectionData));
```

which convert `String[]` to `ArrayList` then `ArrayList` gives us facility of finding element with `indexof()`.

Then in your inner for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < collectionData.length; j++) {
       indexList.add(cd.indexOf(searchName.get(i).toString()));
       break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

`toString()` method of an array returns something similar to `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55`. This is the reason you were getting index value as -1.

Other than the solution sam2090 provided, you can try 2 more options.

Replace

```
indexList.add(collectionData.toString().indexOf(searchName.get(i).toString()))
```

with

```
indexList.add(java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(collectionData, searchName.get(i)))
```

or

Replace `collectionData.toString()` with `java.util.Arrays.toString(values)`